# Excel Amount in Words Formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I found this formula below to convert amounts to words for google spreadsheets and it works perfectly. But now I want to use it in excel 2010 and I get a lot of errors. I also cannot use VBA. Thanks for any help.

=if(or(isBlank(A1),not(isNumber(A1)),A1>=power(10,15)),ifError(1/0,"Error"),trim(arrayFormula(concatenate(if(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))<100,"",choose(int(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))/100)," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine") & " Hundred") & if(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)<>0,if(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))>100," And",if(A1>power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}),choose({1,2,3,4,5},"","","",""," And"),"")),"") & if(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)=0,"",if(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)<20,choose(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine"," Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen"," Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen"),choose(int(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)/10),""," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety") & if(mod(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100),10)=0,"","-" & choose(mod(mod(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100),10),"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")))) & if(trunc(mod(A1,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))=0,"",choose({1,2,3,4,5}," Trillion"," Billion"," Million"," Thousand","")))) & if(A1>=2," Rand",if(A1>=1," Rand","")) & if((round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100=0)+(A1<1),""," And") & if(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100=0,"",if(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100=1," One Cent",if(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100<20,choose(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine"," Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen"," Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen"),choose(int(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100/10),""," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety") & if(mod(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100,10)=0,"","-" & choose(mod(round(A1-trunc(A1),2)*100,10),"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"))) & " Cent"))))

Comment: even Microsoft use vba: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213360

Comment: The file type is xml and does not allow for vba.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers do not need to go above ~100, it may be easier to make two columns, the first with the 1,2,3 etc. and the second with one,two,three etc. Then you can do VLOOKUP() on that table.

An example can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e44dnkg3he8b8il/NumericalToAlpha.xlsx

Comment: I found this website but cant get it to work properly. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/405968-formula-convert-number-text.html

Comment: I added a dropbox link in my answer to an excel sheet. Like I mentioned, it works for as many cells as you care to type out. Are you looking to do this for more then ~100? In the example you link to, they have to reference tables with this data as well, but their solution has a much larger formula with less limits on the size of the number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I need something that can handle values in the millions. For example $ 3 123 456. Thx.

Comment: What is the max on this? I have an idea using `RIGHT()`, but I don't want to spend the time if it is not feasible. Also, can you use arrays/named ranges in xml? I am not familiar with the limitations offhand.